# Failing PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

all. I'm working on creating a contact form with PHP and I just can't get it to work for some reason. The message does not come through and the response "Thank you for your message" does not display. My PHP skills are very novice, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="form-div">
            <?php
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
                    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            ?>
            <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" name="contactForm" action=" <?php echo $self; ?> ">
                <p class="name">
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                </p>
                <p class="email">
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </p>
                <p class="text">
                    <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </p>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                } else {
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
                    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
                    $emailTo = "address@email.com";
                    $subject = "Form for Website";

                    $header = "From: $name <$emailFrom>\r\nReply-To: $emailFrom\r\n";
                    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859\r\n";

                    $message = "<b>From:</b> $name<br><b>Email:</b> $emailFrom<br><b>Message:</b> <br>$comment";

                    mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $header);

                    echo"Thank you for your message.";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: is the code at least entering the else block of the code?

Comment: You might want to remove the extra spaces from the form `action`

Comment: It does not appear to be entering the else block, no. I removed the extra space and it is still a no go.

Comment: Remove action attribute from form tag then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would suggest that the code that sends the email is before any html output - though I'm not 100% sure it would suffer the dreaded `headers already sent` error seen quite often elsewhere. You might wish to consider filtering the POSTed variables too and use `strip_tags` too. Then base the message displayed to the user based upon the return value from the call to `mail`....

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $res=false;

    /* The `PHP_SELF` server var is not considered secure */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['email'],$_POST['name'] ) ){
        @ob_clean();


        $name = strip_tags( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
        $emailFrom = filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        $comment = strip_tags( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );

        $emailTo = "address@email.com";
        $subject = "Form for Website";

        $header = "From: $name <$emailFrom>\r\nReply-To: $emailFrom\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859\r\n";

        $message = "<b>From:</b> $name<br><b>Email:</b> $emailFrom<br><b>Message:</b> <br>$comment";

        /* You do not want any HTML output before trying to send mail */
        $res=@mail( $emailTo, $subject, $message, $header );    
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact form</title>
    </head>
    <body><!-- I don't understand the syntax used in the class attributes of these form elements... -->
        <div id="form-div">
            <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" name="contactForm"><!-- omit the `action` tag to send, by default, to the same page -->
                <p class="name">
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                </p>
                <p class="email">
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </p>
                <p class="text">
                    <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </p>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['email'],$_POST['name'] ) ){
                    echo $res ? 'Thankyou for your mail' : 'Sorry, there was a problem';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, thanks for your response. When I tested your code, I got the following error: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/12/8683312/html/test.php:2) in /home/content/12/8683312/html/test.php on line 3 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/12/8683312/html/test.php:2) in /home/content/12/8683312/html/test.php on line 3

Comment: The error showed just by going to the page, but the form worked - yay! How do I remove the error though?

Comment: This worked! I accidentally put your code after the doctype, which caused the errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `session_start` should be the first thing on the page - you'll notice that the html starts below the initial PHP tags. If you do not need sessions you could remove it - there is nothing on this page that refers to session vars

Answer (score 0):

Check whether php error is turned off in your server. In localhost sending mail will fail if not configured properly. In that case the process exits at mail sending code i.e, `mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $header);` and your thank you message will not execute. Just check it.

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

how about replace

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
```

to

```
if(count($_POST) < 1) {
```